# Android string brake with count

Tags: android, string, count

I want to count the characters in a string and if the counter reach a limit puts a line break. But I don't know how to solve.

I found that word counter, but how to add a break to specific places?e.g after each 4th word.

```
public static int countWords(String s){

    int wordCount = 0;

    boolean word = false;
    int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // if the char is a letter, word = true.
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i != endOfLine) {
            word = true;
            // if char isn't a letter and there have been letters before,
            // counter goes up.
        } else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && word) {
            wordCount++;
            word = false;
            // last word of String; if it doesn't end with a non letter, it
            // wouldn't count without this.
        } else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

Comment: What code do you currently have? What's its result?

Comment: ok, but how to add a \n to original string after the limit, and dont brake a word?

Comment: Save the position(s) where you want to do the \n when you find the condition(s) you want. Then iterate the original string again and add the \n for the position(s) you saved before.

Comment: This needs more elaboration of what you are trying to achieve, can you show us a sample input and output?